# Texture doesn't look the same

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and having problems with the textures. Whenever I import a texture and apply it to the terrain it doesn't look the same, sometimes it's for example way too dark and sometimes it's way too shiny. Here is an example: [image]

I have been googling for a while without finding much about it, does someone know what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Check the Ambient Color under Window>Lighting. May be you are using darker color. Set it to pure White. Enabling Fog can also make the scene darker. Or may be it's the lighting in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this, I expect, is because you are just dropping a texture image onto an object without changing anything. By default, this will create a new *material* asset, which is what is actually added to the object.

Look up [Materials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/materials) if you don't already understand how they work. The default settings are the *Metallic* slider at 0 and the *Shininess* slider at 0.5. Obviously these settings need to be changed depending on the texture, as not every texture is going be a non-metallic, kind of shiny substance.

It is also in these settings that you can add things like Normal Maps, Bump Maps, etc, to make them look more realistic.

Reasons for it being too dark might simply be  that the your lighting isn't reaching that particular surface. In order to have a global light source, add a *Directional Light* to your scene.